# How to get the list of posts with empty content

Tags: content

i make two list theme

1. the posts have featured image and title, but empty content. i want get this list.
2. and other posts with content list.

I don't have any idea, help me please

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')    
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'desc');

$blank_posts = array();

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $post = $posts->the_post();
       $content = get_the_content();
        if(empty($content)) { 
            array_push( $blank_posts, $post);
        }
    endwhile;
endif;

/* print all blank content posts */
print_r($blank_posts);
```

this code doesn't work, Please give me some detailed code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code :

```
$content = get_the_content();
        if(empty($content)) {...}
```

you can replace your code with this :

```
if ($posts->post_content == ''){...}
```

this is not tested just try it i hope useful it.

> EDIT

try this code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'desc');

$blank_posts = array();
$content_post =array();

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
    global $post;
       $content = get_the_content();
        if(empty($content)) { 
            array_push( $blank_posts, $post);
        }else{
            array_push( $content_post, $post);
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
/* print all blank content posts */
var_dump($blank_posts);
var_dump($content_post);

if(!empty($blank_posts)){
    foreach ($blank_posts as $pst) {
        echo "ID= ". $pst->ID . ' : '. "Title= ". $pst->post_title .'<hr />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => ) dont work

Comment: @metalbug Please check edited answer.

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#3100 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(51) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2017-07-31 13:00:46" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(12)

Comment: look <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> this code list all the posts, i want empty content and have content, two list

Comment: help me please...

Comment: @metalbug check edit answer.

Comment: look like good, but output Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 51
            [post_author] => 1   this i Don't understand, sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

You should get the content field directly, and check it by a custom function.

I wrote a simple one for you:

```
function check_empty_content($post_id) {
    $str = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id ) );
    return trim( str_replace( '&nbsp;', '', strip_tags($str) ) ) == '';
}
```

Now you can use this function instead of `empty()`.

Comment: dont work, i need empty content and have content, two list

Comment: The code is tested since I pulled it from my project. You should use `if (check_empty_content(get_the_ID()) { ... } else { ... }` if you want both.

Comment: look <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> this code list all the posts, i want empty content and have content, two list